# How can I add jdk.incubator.foreign package to jdk-19 to fix 'Module not found' error?

Tags: java, java-17

**How can i run jdk-19 with jdk.incubator.foreign?**

I am trying to run a project which require jdk.incubator.foreign package. Is there any way, I can add this package to jdk-19.

The error message is as follows

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.incubator.foreign not found
```

I tried downgrading my jdk to version 17 and 18 but i was getting an another error of unsupported class type

The following is the error when I am executing using jdk 17 and similarly with jdk 18.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ptidej/test/all/TestAllCreators has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

Comment: No, you can't incubator modules are meant to provide a preview/non-final form of a module that's planned to be released in a later JDK. It's like a preview feature in a way. But that means it's **only and exclusively** available in the JDK that provides it. If it isn't provided in a later JDK then that's likely because plans changed or it's been moved to a "proper" module. There's no way to "add-on" missing incubator modules to existing JDKs. This specific one is [now a preview feature in JDK 19](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/19-relnote-issues.html).

Comment: `java.lang.foreign` is now [a (preview) part of `java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/package-summary.html).

Comment: I had written a utility that used jdk.incubator.foreign.  I recently updated the code to use java.lang.foreign.  Trust me, it’s worth the effort.  The new API is easier to work with.